# payment processing with stripe

Tags: 7, commerce

I was just wondering if there was any module that implements the stripe api for payment processing. I'm using drupal 7. Stripe is a new payment processor that people say is better than paypal so I'd like to try them out. they're at **stripe dot com**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1):

There's [no ready module](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/contrib) for this, since stripe.com has https://stripe.com/api so it should be made as custom module [for payment](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/ommerce--modules--payment--commerce_payment.api.php/DC)

Comment: Ok goood info. So, I'll probably take a stab at this. Any pointers, examples on making a payment module would be very welcome. Thank you.

Comment: please see first link, there's lot of modules that for some payment systems integration. Just use it...

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Check out the [Webform Stripe](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_stripe) module which provides a lightweight, powerful integration between Webform and Stripe. From the project page:

> Webform Stripe adds super simple Stripe integration to Webforms, so that submissions can be "purchased".
>
> With this, you can use webforms for event registrations, online donations, or even for simple products where you need to gather additional information from a user.
>
> It uses Stripe Checkout to collect payments as the form is submitted.
>
> There are lots of ways to collect payment for Webforms. Most of them are difficult or require lots of modules. This is super simple solution. If you require more complex workflows or integration with your store, consider the myriad of options available for Commerce, Ubercart, or Payment.